# Crystal Reports c# VS 2012 - Can't add picture to my report, not displaying?

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

I'm working in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate c# and using the designer for creating Crystal reports. I want to add an image in the head section by doing: Rightclick -> Insert -> Picture and then I select the picture (png/bmp) and nothing happens. I tried to do this with an OLE link to the image files as well, but (besides the OLE object) no image shows up.

I checked all around the web but couldn't find a solution to my problem. Any suggestions or ideas as to what can cause this or how I can circumvent the issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok appearently I found the cause for nothing happening by continually trying to make things happen in the designer :p.

Crystal reports is quite buggy when it comes to adding pictures, first of all it does not generate a single error message when something goes wrong with loading image files. For example, Crystal reports can't support gifs or transparent images and will not show any error message when trying to load one.

The second (and in my case most important) cause is that by double clicking an image while loading it immediately places the image under your cursor and when your cursor is outside the drawing surface of your report it will immediately disband your picture. Selecting the image and pressing the Enter key to confirm will allow you to move your picture onto your report.

I hope this will help other people with similiar problems in the future.

Comment: For me, I simply saved my jpg and as a png and it started to show up.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting the image with single click after going to Insert->Picture and then pressing enter to confirm worked for me.